# Can I make a rainbow in shower?

Tags: visible-light, experimental-physics, home-experiment, dispersion

As droplets of shower acts like rain, and say a light bulb will take place of sun. In this scenery, is it possible to make a rainbow?

Comment: In theory, yes.

Comment: Cute idea, but not very practical. An easy way to split light into a spectrum is with a water prism, which can be easily made from a dish of water and a mirror.

Answer (score 6):

In principle it is but you need you need to be aware of the problems.

You need **one** bright source of light of small size like a light bulb with very little of the light being reflected off the walls, ceiling and floor.
This requirement is problematic in that a lot of showers are contained within (white) tiled walls which reflect the light which will make it more difficult to see a rainbow because of this extraneous "background" light.
The light source should preferably not be directly above you, ie in the ceiling, but rather to the side. The reason for not using the spotlight (compact bright source) above a shower is that a (white) base of the shower reflects a great deal of the light which masks any rainbow effect produced.

A potentially **dangerous** way forward is to have the light source (battery powered and waterproof) at the "back" of the shower remote from the door so light from the background is reduced when looking towards the (open) door and beyond.

I do not have a picture of a rainbow in a shower but I have one using a hose in the garden.

[image]

Note (look at the shadows) that you need to be between the light source and the water droplets and you will need to move your head and eyes around to get the angles right to observe a rainbow.

Given the problems I think it unlikely that you will be able to observe a rainbow in a shower without making a special effort to see one but I would be delighted to be proved wrong.
A communal shower area with the walls distant from the water droplets and sunlight coming in through a window might be suitable?

Comment: Above or to the side makes no difference.  What matters is that the light source must be _behind_ you.  That is, you must look in the same direction that the light is shining.  So, if the light source is overhead, and you want to see a rainbow, you must look down through the spray.

Comment: @jameslarge I entirely agree with you. The reason for not using the spotlight (compact bright source) above my shower is that the base of my shower is white plastic which reflects a great deal of the light which masks any rainbow effect produced.

Comment: Yes, if you want to see high-quality rainbows in your shower, then your best option would be a pitch-black shower stall illuminated by one tiny, and very bright halogen bulb.

Comment: The light source should be infinitely far away, so it may be best to use an open air shower and the sun. Another potential problem is that shower droplets may be relatively large, vibrating and nonspherical.

Answer (score 0):

Easy a flash light (waterproof) in the dark. Because the sun shining in darkness of space…
What I want to know is, under this experiment will the rainbow still be curved as it is outside?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/424378)