# Permanent rainbow

Tags: optics, refraction, home-experiment

Yesterday I saw a rainbow that lasted for minutes (typical Hamburg weather; little did I know the record is hours) and googled around a bit. You can easily make a permanent rainbow with [nail polish](https://www.physicscentral.com/experiment/physicsathome/permanent-rainbow.cfm), also permanent rainbows may exist on [large waterfalls](https://www.dreamstime.com/permanent-rainbow-victoria-falls-zimbabwe-largest-africa-length-kilometers-constant-fall-large-body-water-video221933124).

But is there somewhere a construction for a DYI household permanent *water* rainbow? ([Related but unpractical version](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/396236/))

Comment: With a garden fountain, or [sprinkler](https://c8.alamy.com/comp/BDJE75/sprinkler-on-lawn-rainbow-BDJE75.jpg) (outdoors of course)?

Answer (score 2):

I have used 0.25 mm polystyrene beads but not water to produce rainbows so perhaps that can be used for your display?

For the first picture I had the beads in a tray and used a small bright source above the tray.
I used an iPhone to take the picture.

[image]

For the second picture I sprayed a sheet of black paper with artists' spray adhesive and then scattered the polystyrene beads onto the paper to form a layer one bead thick.
I mounted the paper on a wall and illuminated it with a slide projector.

[image]

One interesting effect I did notice whilst looking for the secondary bow.
I did see a second bow but the colour order of both bows was the same - each of my eyes was producing a bow in slightly different positions!
Closing one eye confirmed this.